Help with B Cell Assignments in Single Cell Data
I am trying to assign cell types to the B cell subset of the PBMC 8k dataset from 10x (https://www.10xgenomics.com/datasets/8-k-pbm-cs-from-a-healthy-donor-2-standard-2-1-0). Cell type assignment is tricky, with a lot of overlapping marker genes specified in the literature. I am a bioinformatician, not an immunologist, and though I have found some interesting trends across the subsets of B cells, I want to make sure I don't embarrass myself by using the wrong assignments. Any help would be appreciated. As of now, I think I would call cluster 4 "transitional" or "naive", and cluster 7 "activated" or "plasma". I was previously grouping 19 in with 7, but the presence of B2M and TRAC (which seems more common on T cells, though it has been reported on B cells) is confusing to me...Any advice would be greatly appreciated.





